# React Native Cannot Install

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, reactjs

I am running on windows and following the outline here:https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

However, during the step `npm install` within the project, the output lists dozens of errors:

```
C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\bufferutil>if not d
efined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\n
ode-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node
"" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\buffer
util
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\n
ode_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if n
ot defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\b
in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (n
ode "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\utf-8-
validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp re
build`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fseve
nts@1.0.11
```

How can this be alleviated?

Answer (score 0):

Ah- it looks like the Python env variable needs to be set. Try this:

```
set PYTHON=D:\Python\bin\Python.exe
```

Comment: Ah. I think you just need to set the PYTHON variable then to wherever you placed Python. If not the \bin, then your appdata folder.